# Local IIS vs IIS Express with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have a sample application written in ASP.Net. It works fine when I use IIS Express. It means that my app communicates with database. I've checked that Local IIS doesn't send anything to SQL Server (in SQL Server Profiler). Could you give me some advice? What should I configure?

Comment: What does IIS have to do with connecting to a database?

Comment: What is your connection string? Are you using deprecated or ill-advised features like `user instance` or `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: `<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=mycomputer\servername; Initial Catalog=aspnet-FullCalendar_MVC-20130816144834; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Stop using `User Instance=True` and make sure that you are using the right and the same initial catalog for all connection strings. That doesn't look like a very wise database name, but that's a different issue.